# How to resize multiple images while uploading?

Tags: php, jquery, resize

I have this code of a multi-uploader, the uploader works well. I'm asking for additional code to resize the uploaded Images while uploading.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="formItem">  
    <div id="mulitplefileuploader">Upload</div>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var settings = {
            url: "uploadnew.php",
            method: "POST",
            allowedTypes:"jpg,png,gif,doc,pdf,zip",
            fileName: "myfile",
            multiple: true,
            onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
            {
                $("#status").html("<font color='green'>Upload is success</font>");

            },
            afterUploadAll:function()
            {
                alert("all images uploaded!!");
            },
            onError: function(files,status,errMsg)
            {       
                $("#status").html("<font color='red'>Upload is Failed</font>");
            }
        }
        $("#mulitplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);

    });
    </script>               
</div>
```

And here is the uploadnew.php:

```
<?php
//If directory doesnot exists create it.
$output_dir = "uploads/";

if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
{
    $ret = array();

    $error =$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
    {

        if(!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]['name'])) //single file
        {
            $RandomNum   = time();

            $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['myfile']['name']));
            $ImageType      = $_FILES['myfile']['type']; //"image/png", image/jpeg etc.

            $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
            $ImageExt       = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
            $ImageName      = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);
            $NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNum.'.'.$ImageExt;

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir. $NewImageName);
             //echo "<br> Error: ".$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];

                 $ret[$fileName]= $output_dir.$NewImageName;


        }
        else
        {
            $fileCount = count($_FILES["myfile"]['name']);
            for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
            {
                $RandomNum   = time();

                $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['myfile']['name'][$i]));
                $ImageType      = $_FILES['myfile']['type'][$i]; //"image/png", image/jpeg etc.

                $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
                $ImageExt       = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
                $ImageName      = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);
                $NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNum.'.'.$ImageExt;

                $ret[$NewImageName]= $output_dir.$NewImageName;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i],$output_dir.$NewImageName );




            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($ret);
}
?>
```

Comment: So you just want us to write the code for you, or can you show any attempt that you have made at resizing the images and explain what is not working as expected?

Comment: im new in php , i tried many codes arround , but couldnot how to resize :(

Comment: A simple Google search should easily reveal some approaches that you may investigate... https://www.google.com/search?q=PHP+image+resize&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a  SO is not a coding service. It is geenrally expected that you have made an attempt to solve a problem yourself before asking a question.  that way we can can specific advice around the specific implementation problems you are having.

Answer (score 0):

can you add a foreach($_FILES) {} around the "single file" code you already have to cycle through the files? as it would work fon one file, or one hundred.

Also, a reasonable google search finds quite a few results, but here is one option that with a few tweaks could be adjusted to fit your needs from the following url:

http://www.gilbertocortez.com/blog/php/image-resizing-with-php

```
<?PHP
//Image Target
$pic = ‘images/’.$_GET['pic'];
//Set Max Sizes
$max_height = 48;
$max_width = 48;
//Get Image Size
$size= getimagesize($pic);
//Set Ratios
$width_ratio  = ($size[0] / $max_width);
$height_ratio = ($size[1] / $max_height);
if($width_ratio >=$height_ratio){
    $ratio = $width_ratio; 
} else {
    $ratio = $height_ratio;
}
//Set new size
$new_width    = ($size[0] / $ratio);
$new_height   = ($size[1] / $ratio);
//Set header
header(“Content-Type: image/jpeg”);
//Create Image
$src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($pic);
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width,$new_height);
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $src_img, 0,0,0,0,$new_width,$new_height,$size[0],$size[1]);
imagejpeg($thumb);
imagedestroy($src_img);
imagedestroy($thumb);
?>
```

Comment: im asking about multiimages not only 1 ,

Comment: yes. your PHP would include this resize within the script, or perhaps a function you can call to perform the resize. This should give you some base ideas on how to do this after which you can adjust your current working loops for both the single image option, or the multiple image option.

Comment: thnx , i will try to figure it out .. :)

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
<?php

function imgMaxHeight( $ImageName, $output_dir, $pathToResized, $resizedHeight ) {
    $info = pathinfo($output_dir . $ImageName);
    if ( strtolower($info['extension']) == 'jpg' ) {
      $img = imagecreatefromjpeg( "{$output_dir}{$ImageName}" );
      $width = imagesx( $img );
      $height = imagesy( $img );
      $new_width = floor( $width * ( $resizedHeight / $height ) );
      $new_height = $resizedHeight;
//      $new_width = $thumbWidth;
//      $new_height = floor( $height * ( $thumbWidth / $width ) );
      $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );
      imagecopyresampled( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );
      imagejpeg( $tmp_img, "{$pathToResized}{$ImageName}" );
    }else{
      $img = imagecreatefrompng( "{$output_dir}{$ImageName}" );
      $width = imagesx( $img );
      $height = imagesy( $img );
      $new_width = floor( $width * ( $resizedHeight / $height ) );
      $new_height = $resizedHeight;
//      $new_width = $thumbWidth;
//      $new_height = floor( $height * ( $thumbWidth / $width ) );
      $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );
      imagecopyresampled( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );
      imagepng( $tmp_img, "{$pathToResized}{$ImageName}" );
    }
} //END fn createThumb



//If directory does not exist, create it.
$output_dir = "uploads/";
$img_dir = "path/to/resized_images/";


if(isset($_FILES["myfile"])){
    $ret = array();
    $error =$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];

    { //UNKNOWN EXTRA OPENING BRACE - REMOVE IT

        if(!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]['name'])) //single file
        {
            $RandomNum   = time();

            $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['myfile']['name']));
            $ImageType      = $_FILES['myfile']['type']; //"image/png", image/jpeg etc.

            $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
            $ImageExt       = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
            $ImageName      = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);
            $NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNum.'.'.$ImageExt;

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir. $NewImageName);
            //echo "<br> Error: ".$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];


            imgMaxHeight($ImageName, $output_dir, $img_dir, '400');


            $ret[$fileName]= $output_dir.$NewImageName;
        }
        else
        {
            $fileCount = count($_FILES["myfile"]['name']);
            for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
            {
                $RandomNum   = time();

                $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['myfile']['name'][$i]));
                $ImageType      = $_FILES['myfile']['type'][$i]; //"image/png", image/jpeg etc.

                $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
                $ImageExt       = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
                $ImageName      = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);
                $NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNum.'.'.$ImageExt;

                $ret[$NewImageName]= $output_dir.$NewImageName;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i],$output_dir.$NewImageName );


                imgMaxHeight($ImageName, $output_dir, $img_dir, '400');


            }
        } //END IF(!is_array //single/multi files
    } //UNKNOWN EXTRA CLOSING BRACE - REMOVE IT
    echo json_encode($ret);
} //END if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))

?>
```